# Run Sql file in MYSQL PHPMyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have written the SQL file with on excecuting it is throwing the error as 
mysql> @"C:\Documents and Settings\Hemant\Desktop\create_tables.sql";
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@"C:\
Documents and Settings\Hemant\Desktop\create_tables.sql"' at line 1

on line 1 code is 
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `test`;
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
USE test;

please let me know is i am missing something

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't there a table `test` by default when you setup PHPMyAdmin?

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra semi column after `test`.

Try removing it and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: i have updated this to now CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `test`;
 
USE test;

Comment: Did it work? `CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS test DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci; USE test;` should have worked, too (and might be required). Also... there's a http://stackoverflow.com/faq that will explain what is supposed to be your next action...